# HashMap implementation of DataSource interface : nextRow() method?

Tags: java, data-structures

I would like to implement a `DataSource` interface (in Java) which, among other things, allows you to acquire the `nextRow()` from the data. I initially just want to implement the data store via HashMaps, but it would be cool to abstract away from the underlying data structure, and provide an interface as mentioned.

Does this sound like a good idea? Providing the `nextRow()` method for the `HashMap` implementation seems somewhat messy - I guess I need to provide an iterator on the collection view of the data. And I guess I'd need to provide a `resetIterator` method as well?

To provide a few more details:

- I am thinking the `newRow()` method will return `HashMap<String, String>`
- `HashMap` implementation of the data store will be `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`

Any thoughts and comments are much appreciated!

Comment: Any specific reason for using a Map of Maps? A List of Maps sounds like a better option.

Comment: Basically I (in the current example) am taking the data from a csv file, and I want each row to be uniquely identifiable by a certain piece of data (either the data from one column, or potentially a combination of several columns).
So the rows will be returned as HashMap<colName, colValue>, and they will all be stored in a HashMap with the id value as the key

Answer (score 0):

The [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface does expose iterators via the [.keySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29), [.values()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), and [.entrySet()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) methods.  You could use one of these behind the scenes to do what you have in mind.

On a side note, a HashMap for each data row is a lot of overhead.  If you can fix a set of columns in advance, it would be a lot cheaper to use a List (ArrayList maybe), or even just a plain array, to represent each row.